# Java class declaration - having a '.' and static classes

Tags: java, android

Hi I was looking at this syntax from the Android API and found it a bit weird.

```
java.lang.Object  
   ↳    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options
```

public static class
BitmapFactory.Options

I have never seen a class with a '.' in the middle of it. Why didn't they just call the class 'BitmapFactoryOptions'?

Then I was confused even more because I saw this code in a book

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
```

BitmapFactory is static yet we are creating an instance of it?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @dasblinkenlight answer, the code could look like:

```
public class BitmapFactory {
  public static class Options {
  }
}
```

And that's indeed the case, see [source code for BitmapFactory](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L38).

Answer (score 2):

They did not name the class with a dot in it (that would be illegal). All they did was adding a static inner class called `Options` - a member class of the `BitmapFactory` class.

This is a common way of hiding classes inside their outer classes when the class or an interface in question has no meaning on its own, and must be interpreted only in the context of its outer class.

Of course the solution that you suggested (naming the class `BitmapFactoryOptions`) is perfectly valid as well. However, it gives a false impression that the class can be useful on its own.

Perhaps the most commonly used example of this is the [`Map.Entry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface: map entries have meaning only when there is a map around them, so the nesting is very useful.

Comment: Oh thank you that makes sense now. I know what nested classes are, that it why this looked a bit strange to me. I thought it was a top level static class, which I knew was illegal.

Comment: @jimbo123 to add have a look at Look at the code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java/

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other class variable and class method, there can be class within a class as well. The following example shows all three kinds of class members accessed using the same syntax.

```
public class Person{

     public static long totalPopulation;
     public static void calculateAge(Date dob){
     }
     public static class Address{
     }
}
```

All of these will be accessed in the same way. i.e.,

```
Person.totalPopulation = 700_000_0000L;
Person.calculateAge(person.getDOB());
Person.Address address = new Person.Address();
```